# How to remove duplicate records from LINQ query

Tags: linq, duplicates, entity, viewmodel

[image]

This is how my database looks like and my code which gets all data from database by WhID

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var viewModel =
             (from Wh in db.Werehouses
             join WhK in db.WerehouseKeys on Wh.WhID equals WhK.WhID
             join Itm in db.Items on Wh.WhID equals Itm.WhID
             where Wh.WhID == id
             select new WerehouseViewModel { Werehouse = Wh, WerehouseKey = WhK, Item = Itm });
        if (viewModel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

But when I want to show it in View it shows duplicate Keys (e.g. Key 1, Key 2, Key 3, Key 1, Key 2, Key 3, etc.) and Items (Item 1, Item 2, Item 1, Item 2, etc.). How can I delete duplicates from query?

This is my ViewModel

```
public class WerehouseViewModel
{
    public Werehouse Werehouse { get; set; }
    public WerehouseKey WerehouseKey { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are joining `Werehouses` (one) to 2 different (many) entities, so the result is a cartesian product of the related `WerehouseKeys` and `Items` records. You might need to consider changing your view model and use group joins.

Comment: Well thanks for advice, could you please show me how would you edit it?

Comment: I would make `WerehouseViewModel` to be something like this `public Werehouse Werehouse { get; set; } public List<WerehouseKey> WerehouseKeys { get; set; } public List<Item> Items { get; set; }`

Comment: It didn't help, the viewModel contains 15 records so I need to do something in query to eliminate them, but don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how are you going to visualize it, but you have one master `Werehouse` entity with 2 detail `WerehouseKey` and `Item` entities, which are unrelated to each other, thus cannot be combined in a single record like your current view model.

The only way I see to represent such data is to change the view model to:

```
public class WerehouseViewModel
{
    public Werehouse Werehouse { get; set; }
    public List<WerehouseKey> WerehouseKeys { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and populate it using two [`Group Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_1)s:

```
var viewModel =
    (from Wh in db.Werehouses
     join WhK in db.WerehouseKeys on Wh.WhID equals WhK.WhID into keys
     join Itm in db.Items on Wh.WhID equals Itm.WhID into items
     where Wh.WhID == id
     select new WerehouseViewModel
     { 
         Werehouse = Wh,
         WerehouseKeys = keys.ToList(),
         Items = items.ToList()
     })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That is the answer for my question. Thank you so much!